# Oracle Stored Procedure posing a prob

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, dbeaver

[EDIT]Editing the code to reflect changes coming from comments

I have a problem with one of the stored procedures I'm trying to create in an Oracle database.

The goal is to update every table which has an `indiv` column.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_majUserOnAllK (lastU IN VARCHAR2, newU IN VARCHAR2)
AS 
BEGIN
  FOR item IN (
        select table_name , owner 
        from all_tab_columns 
        where column_name = 'INDIV' AND OWNER ='K'
    )
    LOOP                
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE K.' ||  item.table_name || ' SET indiv = :newValue WHERE indiv = :oldValue' USING newU, lastU;
    END LOOP;
END sp_majUserOnAllK;

exec sp_majUserOnAllK( 'hum','hum');
```

Problem is, when I try to execute the stored procedure, I got an error message with no detail at all ('non valid SQL').

I tried taking the code out of the stored procedure. And there, it works. Only the beginning is changing to :

```
DECLARE
    newU NVARCHAR2(50);
    lastU NVARCHAR2(50);
    req VARCHAR2(100);
    CURSOR ctable IS
        select table_name , owner from all_tab_columns where column_name = 'INDIV' AND OWNER ='KEXPLOIT';

    BEGIN

        newU := 'hum';
        lastU := 'hum';
        FOR item IN ctable
            ....
```

Like that, it works perfectly and does exactly what it is supposed to do.

As the only difference is the assignation of the variable, I think I may have a problem with my procedure declaration but I can't find a solution. The compilation is ok.

Any idea ?

Comment: `'non valid SQL'` is not an Oracle error message. Probably that is from whatever desktop dev tool you are using, trying to tell you that the procedure is invalid due to the `return 1` line that kfinity mentioned. Ideally you would use a tool that highlights lines with compilation errors.

Comment: Absolutely, I'm using dbeaver.

For the "return 1", it's a test I tried and forgot to remove when I wrote this question. It is not in the sp.

Comment: Your updated procedure works fine for me. Maybe show us more details of how you're running it. What table names does it update? Are any of them case-sensitive?

Comment: The how I run it is just bellow. A simple "exec sp_majUserOnAllK( 'test','restet');".

It returns a bunch of tables. Can't really give any detail cause I'm working on doing a proprietary application job.

I have to update a user. But If I do, as they are no foreign keys, we are loosing a lot of information.

But, I know every table have the indinv column has a key. So I iterate through those tables to do the cascade update.

Comment: Regardless of how (or even "if") you are able to solve your current problem, are you ever going to solve the root cause of all of it? You are using a *relational* database product (Oracle); why are there no foreign keys in your tables?

Comment: Cause most softwares I have encountered in the medical field are pile of garbages. I am literally obligated to send them reports showing them they are creating vues/join on massive table with absolutely no indexes. It is insane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A five-second Google search on "dbeaver exec command" brought this up among the first few hits:

https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/749

In it, we learn that `EXEC` is not supported by dbeaver.

`EXEC` is an SQL*Plus command. It is not Oracle SQL, and it is not PL/SQL. SQL*Plus is a shell program of sorts for interacting with Oracle databases; it has its own language, distinct from SQL and PL/SQL.

SQL Developer and Toad (and perhaps other similar programs) support (most of) SQL*Plus, but apparently dbeaver (with which I am not familiar) does not.

The link I copied above suggests using the `CALL` command instead. See the link for examples.

As an aside, when we use `EXEC` in SQL*Plus and SQL Developer, there is no semicolon at the end of the procedure call. Adding an unnecessary semicolon, however, does not throw an error (SQL*Plus is, apparently, smart enough to simply ignore it).

Comment: I think they are talking about executing command from bash/cmd... "echo param.sql
isql -U%1 -P%2 -S%3 -i %5\param.sql" Absolutely not what I am trying to do. Futhermore, I have tried on sqlplus, the oracle command line client.

Comment: @C.Dumange - I am sorry, I added the wrong link. I fixed that now. It is the third (not the first) link on the Google search page; although I guess the position on a Google search varies over time and perhaps also by user. Anyway, the link in my Answer is now the one I meant.

Comment: This makes sense. dBeaver could be trying to tell you that `exec` is invalid SQL (which is correct, it is not SQL). What if you try `call sp_majUserOnAllK('hum','hum');` or else `begin sp_majUserOnAllK('hum','hum'); end;`

Comment: You killed me. Thanks a lot. Never thought exec could not be pl/sql... It works using CALL.

Comment: @C.Dumange - the explanation about `EXEC` not being PL/SQL has been in my answer since yesterday. I guess you followed the link, it was the wrong one, so you didn't read the rest of my answer? ;-)

Comment: I... Heu... Hum... The sky is really blue today don't you think ? ;-)

Comment: So, no procedure you have ever tried to run using `exec` has ever worked, and yet you needed detailed diagnosis for this particular one?

Comment: Most of my db experience is on SqlServer. Which manage Exec command.

New job with application using Oracle. Never had to create a procedure yet.

Answer (score 3):

Your procedure's syntax is not correct. Try this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_majUserOnAllK (lastU IN VARCHAR2, newU IN VARCHAR2)
IS 
  req VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  FOR item IN (select table_name , owner from all_tab_columns where column_name = 'INDIV' AND OWNER ='K')
    LOOP                
        req := 'UPDATE K.' ||  item.table_name || ' SET indiv = :newValue WHERE indiv = :oldValue';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE req USING newU, lastU;
    END LOOP;
  -- return 1; -- note: procedures do not return values
END;
/
```

Comment: `IS` and `AS` are interchangeable in `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE`. `AS` reads better for standalone objects.

Comment: Got a "REQ" as to be declared error.


Tried to add a DECLARE but I fell back to the old error. Love the removing of the cursor tho ^^

Comment: Compiles for me. Is it actually not valid, or is that just dBeaver not understanding PL/SQL? You don't need to add a `declare` section anyway, it's already there (declare what you want above `begin`). The cursor is not removed, it's inlined as part of the loop.

Comment: To remove this problem, I tried removing completly the variable. I execute the request directly.

I compile too, but when I execute, still the same error. I edited first post to reflect changes.